# Use StreamWriter to store in a specific path

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to specify where I should store the created file using StreamWriter:

```
string getCurrentPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;
StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(@"" +getCurrentPath + "\\NDependProject\\OceanAPIDependencies.xml");
writeFile.Close();
```

I get this error message:

> ```
>     Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part
>  of the path 'D:\Project_Summer\ExtensionDirectoryTraversal\ExtensionDirectoryTr
> aversal\bin\Debug\NDependProject\OceanAPIDependencies.xml'.
>    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, I
> nt32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions o
> ptions, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolea
> n useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access,
> FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean
> bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>    at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean che
> ckHost)
>    at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encodin
> g, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
>    at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path)
>    at ExtensionDirectoryTraversal.Program.Main(String[] args) in d:\Project_Summ
> er\ExtensionDirectoryTraversal\ExtensionDirectoryTraversal\Program.cs:line
> ```
>
> 15
>       Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: I would guess that there's no `NDependProject` directory under `bin\Debug`. The error message is quite straightforward. By the way, it would be better to use `System.IO.Path.Combine` to construct file names - that way you don't need to know whether what you obtained from `CurrentDirectory` ends with a \ or not.

Comment: NDependProject is there, I created the directory :) but I want to specify to STORE the file there. Which means the .exe file in debug is outside of the NDepend project

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely reason is stated in the error message: "Could not find a part of the path" - stream writer will not create folders, only files.

Using [Directory.CreateDirectory](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.createdirectory%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and related functions to make sure folder exists.

Side note: please use special [Path.Combine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.combine.aspx) method to construct paths instead of manual string concatenation.